# iOS: NSRunLoop on a Custom Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsrunloop

I am run `NSRunLoop` with `NSTimer` on a custom cell in order to continuously update the "Valid Until" `UILabel`. It works fine until I close the tableView, the `NSRunLoop` continues the time countdown. I use `dealloc`, but seems it doesn't drain `NSRunLoop` and `NSTimer`.

```
-(void)dealloc {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
    [_timer invalidate];
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
    _runner = nil; // NSRunLoop
}
```

How can I kill the `NSRunLoop` when a cell gets released? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't _dare_ using NSRunLoop in that way. You are just asking for trouble.

Comment: My up vote for this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approaching the problem using the current run loop will get you in all kinds of trouble. The simplest way to approach the problem is by having an `NSTimer` property on your cell and start/stop it when the cell `willDisplay`/`willEndDisplay`.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    var timer: NSTimer?

    func startTimer() -> Void {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateUI:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func stopTimer() -> Void {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    func updateUI(sender: NSTimer?) -> Void {
        // update your label here
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if let cell = cell as? CustomCell {
            cell.startTimer()
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if let cell = cell as? CustomCell {
            cell.stopTimer()
        }
    }

}
```